# sharepoint wss 3.0 user domain

Tags: sharepoint

I've inherited a sharepoint wss 3.0 farm that is pulling users from 2 different domains, say domainA and domainB. So if I go into Add User and Browse, and type Smith, it is coming up with domainA\jsmith and domainB\jsmith. The company has moved away from domainA and uses only domainB now. So I want to remove domainA from the sharepoint configuration. I don't need to migrate existing sharepoint users, I just want for the domainA users to stop showing up when new users are added. I've been through every page I can find in Central Administration and I don't see where the names of the domain controller(s) are specified. It is using windows auth / NTLM.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at peoplepicker-searchadcustomquery property. You can setup an LDAP query which will allows you to specify which users are shown.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262988.aspx

To restrict a search for a distribution list to only be corp.fabrikam.com and ntdev.corp.fabrikam.com, use the following syntax:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -url http://contoso-370
-pn peoplepicker-distributionlistsearchdomains
-pv corp.fabrikam.com;dev.corp.fabrikam.com
```

The domain name should be a Domain Name Service (DNS) name and should be separated by a semicolon. If no values are set, all trusted domains or the domains listed in the configuration are searched.   To view the current setting for the distributionlistsearchdomains property, use the following syntax:

> stsadm -o getproperty -pn
>   peoplepicker-distributionlistsearchdomains

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/b6b02e06-5b8c-41fb-be20-b8bf488bbe7e